# Why does my IF Statement not execute

Tags: python, string, if-statement, edx

The point of the excerise I am doing is to write a program that prints the longest substring of `s` in which the letters occur in alphabetical order. 
For example, if `s = 'azcbobobegghakl'`, then your program should print:

> Longest substring in alphabetical order is: beggh

In the case of ties, print the first substring. For example, if `s = 'abcbcd'`, then your program should print:

> Longest substring in alphabetical order is: abc

I have run tests and it works on most of the strings I put in, but this one is problematic.

On step 15, it should compare `2 > 0` which is true, but it does not execute,
can someone explain this? Where am I making a mistake?

My code looks like this:

```
s = 'zodworqozid'
curstring = [0]
longest = [0]
for i in range(1,len(s)):
    if s[i] >= str(curstring[-1]):
        curstring+= s[i]
        if len(curstring) > len(longest):
            longest = curstring
    else:
        curstring = s[i]

print('Longest substring in alphabetical order is:', longest)
```

[I am using python tutor to help visualize the steps](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit)

Comment: `len([0]) = 1` - if you want to initialise an empty list you should use `longest = []`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
curstring = [0]
longest = [0]
```

you are creating two lists with one element inside, which is an integer (0).

Later, here:

```
if s[i] >= str(curstring[-1]):
```

you are checking if a given letter has a higher value than the last element on the list. As Python is [zero-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering), you start from the letter 'o' (because it has index 1, which happens to be the first one in your range list).

```
for i in range(1,len(s)):
```

Char (letter) comparision is based on [ASCII table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters), thus any letter given would have a "higher value" than 0 ('o' is 111).

Because the condition from the second block of code is true, the letter 'o' is added to the list in this block:

```
curstring+= s[i]
```

and after that, the list *curstring* has two elements on it: 0 and 'o'.

```
if len(curstring) > len(longest):
```

Here you're comparing *curstring* (described above) and *longest* which is a list with one element in it: 0 (as you created the list with one element in the first block of code described above). The condition is true (2 elements is more than one element), so *longest* now [points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)) to the same list as *curstring* and thus has two elements (and the length = 2).

Later on, as you can see in the visualiser you provided, the *curstring* reference variable doesn't point to the list. It's type is changed when this line is executed:

```
curstring = s[i]
```

so later, when a char is added, when the 15. step is executed it turns out to be a two letter string "dw". That string is compared with the list *longest* with two elements (which was described above). The String "dw" is of length 2 and the list is of length 2, that's why the condition is false.

You should read a bit about types in Python and how the variables are created and maintained in the code - it would help you to catch those small mistakes. Bear in mind that Python has a different syntax when it comes to lists than languages like C++ or Java - I assume that you have written that code

```
curstring = [0]
longest = [0]
```

based on experiance with arrays/lists in other languages. Empty list in Python is created like this:

```
new_list = []
```

Answer (score 0):

Bug 1:

```
curstring = [0]
```

You'll want to initialize your `curstring` with the first character in `s` (instead of a list containing the integer `0`). I see that you already know how to do this in your code. (i.e. `s[0]`) This is so that your subsequent code will correctly compare the next character to the first character in `s`.

Bug 2:

```
longest = [0]
```

You'll want to initialize `longest` as an empty <strike>list</strike> `str` (i.e. `""`) instead of a `list` containing integer `0`. This is because you don't need list functionality in `longest` as you're directly returning a `str`.

<strike>Bug 3:</strike>

```
longest = curstring
```

You'll want to make a copy of `curstring` instead of linking `longest` to `curstring`. Do this with either `list(curstring)` or `curstring[:]`. No bug here. I misread `curstring` as a `list` when it's a `str`.

Comment: If `curstring` is a string, why the copy for `longest`? It's not as if the object is mutable.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You're right, I misread `curstring` as a `list` instead of a `str`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly do you mean by "On step 15, it should compare 2>0 which is true, but it does not execute, can someone explain this? where am i making a mistake?". But look at your code,

```
curstring = [0]
if s[i] >= str(curstring[-1]):
```

These two statements mean when i==1, Condition s[i] >= str(curstring[-1]) is always true, which is not right in when s[1]

To correct it. Set initial value of curstring to s[0], "curstring = s[0]" will work. One more suggestion. I think "if s[i]>= s[i-1]" is more readable.

Hope this will help.